# Sublime Text 3: Find my cursor after scrolling?

Tags: editor, sublimetext3

So, while using Sublime Text 3, I often find myself scrolling through a file looking for some function, but then wishing to return my viewport to wherever I left my cursor.  Unfortunately, I frequently have no idea where I left the cursor and I end up having to scroll endlessly just to figure out where I was.

To solve this problem, is there any way to enable cursor tracking in the minimap (so I could just click that spot and go back)?  Or alternatively, is there a shortcut that will center the screen around my cursor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the curser by pressing right-arrow left-arrow and the view will scroll to it.

This works with almost any editor.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be the keyboard shortcut: `⌃L` -- "Scroll to Selection"

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add `"highlight_line": true,` to your user settings. It keeps the cursor line highlighted.